# Iterate and get unique values from JSON for some indexes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm getting data back from my PHP using a query like this:

`SELECT objective,signal_type,signal_name FROM signals WHERE channel="Email"`

The data comes back like this:

```
[
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "CPM"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Click-thru Rate"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Frequency"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Interaction Rate"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Viewability"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Display Time"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Impression"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Reach"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "Cost per Action"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "ROI/ROAS"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Avg Order Value"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Conversion"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Revenue"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "Cost per Click"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Avg Interaction Time"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Conversion Rate"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Click"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Interaction"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Interaction Time"
    }
]
```

I can append this all to a table like so:

```
$.each(data, function(index, key) {
 $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>'+key.objective+'</td><td>'+key.signal_type+'</td><td>'+key.signal_name+'</td></tr>');
                });
```

This yields a perfectly accurate table, but not an eye-pleasing table. I get something like this:

```
| Signal Type | Signal Types | Available Signals    |
|-------------|--------------|----------------------|
| Awareness   | Efficiency   | CPM                  |
| Awareness   | Quality      | Click-thru Rate      |
| Awareness   | Quality      | Frequency            |
| Awareness   | Quality      | Interaction Rate     |
| Awareness   | Quality      | Viewability          |
| Awareness   | Volume       | Display Time         |
| Awareness   | Volume       | Impression           |
| Awareness   | Volume       | Reach                |
| Conversion  | Efficiency   | Cost per Action      |
| Conversion  | Efficiency   | ROI/ROAS             |
| Conversion  | Quality      | Avg Order Value      |
| Conversion  | Volume       | Conversion           |
| Conversion  | Volume       | Revenue              |
| Engagement  | Efficiency   | Cost per Click       |
| Engagement  | Quality      | Avg Interaction Time |
| Engagement  | Quality      | Conversion Rate      |
| Engagement  | Volume       | Click                |
| Engagement  | Volume       | Interaction          |
| Engagement  | Volume       | Interaction Time     |
```

(Note that the header is "hard coded" in my HTML)

What I'd ideally like to have is something like this:

```
| Signal Type | Signal Types | Available Signals    |
|-------------|--------------|----------------------|
| Awareness   | Efficiency   | CPM                  |
|             | Quality      | Click-thru Rate      |
|             |              | Frequency            |
|             |              | Interaction Rate     |
|             |              | Viewability          |
|             | Volume       | Display Time         |
|             |              | Impression           |
|             |              | Reach                |
| Conversion  | Efficiency   | Cost per Action      |
|             |              | ROI/ROAS             |
|             | Quality      | Avg Order Value      |
|             | Volume       | Conversion           |
|             |              | Revenue              |
| Engagement  | Efficiency   | Cost per Click       |
|             | Quality      | Avg Interaction Time |
|             |              | Conversion Rate      |
|             | Volume       | Click                |
|             |              | Interaction          |
|             |              | Interaction Time     |
```

The difference here is that there are distinct values in the columns based on the column before. Any thoughts on how to get to this output? Note that I'm able to adjust my SQL query or my javascript/jquery (or both) depending on what's most efficient.

Comment: In Javascript I would test the value if `objective` and `signal type` are the same as before insert blank otherwise print.

Comment: @Mouser Not sure what you're suggesting here. I only have `signal_type` in my data set, not `signal_types`. Did you mean `signal_name`?

Comment: see my updated comment or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the value is used before. If so print a blank string, if not print the new value.

This translates to your appending code:

```
storedObjective = "";
storedSignal_type = "";
$.each(data, function(index, key) {

    if (key.objective == storedObjective)
    {
        print_1 = "";
    }
    else
    {
        print_1 = objective;
        storedObjective = key.objective;
    }
    if (key.signal_type == storedSignal_type)
    {
        print_2 = "";
    }
    else
    {
        print_2 = key.signal_type;
        storedSignal_type = key.signal_type;
    } 

  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>'+print_1+'</td><td>'+print_2+'</td><td>'+key.signal_name+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this will get everything into the right place (i.e., right column) in the table lined up in the correct row.

Comment: @jonmrich, you still print the table cell, only insert a blank string instead of the value.

Comment: Thanks...I tried, this, but it yields the same thing as my original code...the unique values aren't left out.

Comment: @jonmrich You used the example as it is now?

Comment: Figured out part of the problem...having the variables defined in the loop keeps resetting them. If I move them out, this almost works...just putting the wrong data in a couple places.

Comment: Figured it all out...the line `print_2 = objective;` needs to be `print_2 = key.signal_type;` and it works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry...one more thing...any thoughts of the best way to add a border between the "rows" that include the distinct "main" rows (e.g. under the rows that have "Reach"  and the one that has "Revenue" in it from my question)

Comment: Oeh that's more challenging. However, you need to look ahead if a change is coming. Basically `array[index+1].objective != storedObjective` than add `class` to `tr`.

Comment: Got it...I'll take a shot. Thanks.

Comment: `[index+1].objective` in my each always comes back as undefined.