# IF statement checking for empty strings always returns true

Tags: javascript

```
storedObjective = "";
storedSignal_type = "";
$.each(data, function(index, key) {

    if (key.objective == storedObjective)
    {
        print_1 = "";
    }
    else
    {
        print_1 = key.objective;
        storedObjective = key.objective;
    }
    if (key.signal_type == storedSignal_type)
    {
        print_2 = "";
    }
    else
    {
        print_2 = key.signal_type;
        storedSignal_type = key.signal_type;
    }

    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>'+print_1+'</td><td>'+print_2+'</td><td>'+key.signal_name+'</td></tr>');
    console.log(print_1);
    console.log(print_2);


    if (print_1==="" && print_2==="")
    {
        $('tr').addClass('yes')
    }
    else{
        $('tr').addClass('no')
    }
});
```

All of the first part of the code works fine. But at the very end, my `if` always evaluates as `true` even though if I `console.log` these variables it definitely shouldn't be. What am I missing here?

Comment: Some context would help. For example what do the variables hold, and why

Comment: How can we help if we don't know what values the variables contain?

Comment: How do you know that it always evaluates as true? Have you put a breakpoint inside that block or a console.log() statement inside it to verify that?

Comment: Downvote from me - your question is too vague. Please provide context. For all I know the previous 2 statements are `var print_1="";var print_2=print_1;`

Comment: Okay...fair enough. Just posted the entire code.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Just updated with the full context.

Comment: @BobbyJack Looking at the HTML that is rendered...every `tr` has the `class` "yes"

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Comment: @brso05 No...they are different. Just placeholders. I need to add different classes depending on how the `if` evaluates. They could be `bob` and `jeff` or whatever.

Comment: @jonmrich always best to ensure what you think is happening rather than assuming - for example, something else could be setting those classes to "yes"

Comment: @BobbyJack My code's pretty simple. Nothing else is adding, but fair point.

Comment: @Jecoms This question is a follow on to this question that has the full result of `data` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467608/iterate-and-get-unique-values-from-json-for-some-indexes

Comment: But the `tr`'s also have the class `no`, right?

Comment: @Redu `addClass` is a jQuery method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the class (yes/no) to every existing row, so if the `if` matches once, all existing table rows will get that class - and the same for if `else` matches. You could simplify the `append` and add the class right there.

```
var className = print_1==="" && print_2==="" ? 'yes' : 'no';
$('#myTable').append('<tr class="' + className + '"><td>'+print_1+'</td><td>'+print_2+'</td><td>'+key.signal_name+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Thanks...this is "working" but not adding the classes to the correct rows.

Comment: Then your variables don't hold what you are expecting, or the logic behind the if is wrong. If it's just yes where it should be no, switch it in the ternary @jonmrich

Comment: Damn...actually it does work. I just need to make some adjustments to how I'm rendering. Thanks!

Comment: Did this: `var className = print_1!="" && print_2!="" ? 'yes' : 'no';` and instead of my CSS putting a border on bottom...it puts on top. Works perfectly, but would have never gotten there without your assist.

Comment: Hmm, I think you've missed the point of what the OP tries to do @VanquishedWombat . The answer does this, and explains your point about _every tr_ too...

Comment: @baao Apologies I re-read your answer and concur you do point out the cause. I still think Jecoms answer is a better overall solution. Anyway, +1 for your answer. Erased my prior comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the yes/no class only to the current element in your for each, otherwise every `tr` is going to have yes/no if any of the other elements met the conditional.

Here, only the current element is given a class:

```
let $nextRow = $('<tr><td>'+print_1+'</td><td>'+print_2+'</td> <td>'+key.signal_name+'</td></tr>');

if (print_1==="" && print_2==="")  
    $nextRow.addClass('yes');
else 
    $nextRow.addClass('no');

$('#myTable').append($nextRow);
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "CPM"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Click-thru Rate"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Frequency"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Interaction Rate"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Viewability"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Display Time"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Impression"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Awareness",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Reach"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "Cost per Action"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "ROI/ROAS"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Avg Order Value"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Conversion"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Conversion",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Revenue"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Efficiency",
        "signal_name": "Cost per Click"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Avg Interaction Time"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Quality",
        "signal_name": "Conversion Rate"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Click"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Interaction"
    },
    {
        "objective": "Engagement",
        "signal_type": "Volume",
        "signal_name": "Interaction Time"
    }
];

storedObjective = "";
storedSignal_type = "";
$.each(data, function(index, key) {

    if (key.objective == storedObjective)
    {
        print_1 = "";
    }
    else
    {
        print_1 = key.objective;
        storedObjective = key.objective;
    }
    if (key.signal_type == storedSignal_type)
    {
        print_2 = "";
    }
    else
    {
        print_2 = key.signal_type;
        storedSignal_type = key.signal_type;
    } 

   let $nextRow = $('<tr><td>'+print_1+'</td><td>'+print_2+'</td> <td>'+key.signal_name+'</td></tr>');


    if (print_1==="" && print_2==="")
    {   
        $nextRow.addClass('yes');
    } 
    else{
        $nextRow.addClass('no');
    }
  $('#myTable').append($nextRow);
});
```

```css
.yes {
  background-color: green;
}

.no {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. My console.logs show that they aren't always empty.

Comment: In your code...all rows are red. That's not what I was hoping to accomplish. What's the fix?

Comment: They all have both classes since you never remove classes, you added the yes/no class to every `tr`.

Comment: @jonmrich You just need to only add the class to the current element you're appending.

Comment: +1 for answer that identifies and solves the issue with a snippet illustrating creation of a new element as a variable before appending.